# Probability of two opposite events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose there is string of eight bits, e.g.:

> 00100110

Bits are randomly chosen from the string. All choices are done equally likely.

Probability of choosing $0$:
$p_0 = \frac{5}{8} = 0.625$

Prob. of choosing $1$:
$p_1 = \frac{3}{8} = 0.375$

Suppose you have already chosen $0$ or $1$. Probability of choosing opposite char, and then again opposite char, is given with: $p(0 \wedge 1) = p_0 p_1 = 0.234$.

Without the "you have already chosen $0$ or $1$ ...", the probability would be: $p(0\wedge 1) = 2p_0 p_1 = 0.468$

Correct?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Are you choosing one bit from the 8 given bits at random?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not described with complete clarity. So some assumptions are needed in order to produce an answer. We  assume that you are picking one of the $8$ locations independently and at random $3$ times, with all choices equally likely.  In particular, it is assumed that repetition of location is allowed.

The probability of getting the bit sequence $0$, $1$, $0$ is then $\frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{8}$, and the probability of getting the bit sequence $1$, $0$, $1$ is $\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{8}$. Add. Our probability is 
$$ \frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{8}+\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{8}.$$
This simplifies to $\dfrac{15}{64}$.

**Remark:** The number $\dfrac{15}{64}$ is precisely your number $p_0p_1$. There is good structural reason for that. However, I think that the detailed analysis above is more informative, since it generalizes readily to other situations.

If repetition of location is *not* allowed, the analysis is quite similar, but the numbers change. We get
$$ \frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{6}+\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{7}\cdot\frac{2}{6}.$$

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you elaborate on the structural reason?

Comment: Whatever the probabilities $p_0$ and $p_1$ are, they add up to $1$. We are adding $p_0^2p_1$ and $p_1^2p_0$. This is $p_0p_1(p_0+p_1)$, which is just $p_0p_1$. But if we were interested in the probability of ($0101$ **or** $1010$), we would not get the pleasant simplification.

Comment: Thanks that is interesting to me, because in general I am trying to exploit the opposite relation between $p_0$ and $p_1$. For example, suppose that there is a moveable head, like in Turing machine, pointing at a char. We are interested in "cycle" i.e. in moving to opposite char, and then to opposite-opposite char. The sum up to 1.0 that you described corresponds to fact, that head is always at some char when starting the cycle, either 0 or 1.